# shallow and deep copies in pytorch dataloader and/or __getitem__ function

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I ran into an issue with a custom pytorch dataloader that, I think, has to do with shallow and deep copies inside the `__getitem__()` function. However, there is some behavior I do not understand. And I do not know if it is coming from the pytorch dataloader class or somewhere else.

I created a minimal working example based on my own complex use case. Originally, I had a dataset saved as `.hdf5` that I load in `__init__()`. For the NN, I want the elements normalized to 1 (I divide by their sum) and have the sum returned separately. :

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
# create dataset with fixed seed
np.random.seed(1234)
data = np.random.rand(20, 4)
print(data)
# create custom dataset class

class TestDataset(Dataset):
    """ Test dataset to illustrate bug in get_item """

    def __init__(self, data_array, transform=None, apply_logit=True, with_noise=False):
        """
        Args:
            data_array (np.array): representing data loaded from hdf5 file or so
            transform (None, callable or 'norm'): if data should be transformed
            apply_logit (bool): if logit transform should be applied at the end
            with_noise (bool): if noise should be applied in each call
        """

        self.data = data_array

        self.transform = transform
        self.apply_logit = apply_logit
        self.with_noise = with_noise


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()

        data = self.data[idx]

        if self.with_noise:
            data = add_noise(data)

        data_sum = data.sum(axis=(-1), keepdims=True)

        if self.transform:
            if self.transform == 'norm':
                data /= (data_sum + 1e-16) # this should be avoided
            else:
                data = self.transform(data)

        if self.apply_logit:
            data = logit_trafo(data)

        sample = {'data': data, 'data_sum': data_sum.squeeze()}

        return sample

def get_dataloader(data_array, device, batch_size=2, apply_logit=True, with_noise=False, normed=False):

    kwargs = {'num_workers': 2, 'pin_memory': True} if device.type is 'cuda' else {}

    dataset = TestDataset(data_array, transform='norm' if normed else None, apply_logit=apply_logit,
                              with_noise=with_noise)
    return DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, **kwargs)

def add_noise(input_tensor):
    noise = np.random.rand(*input_tensor.shape)*1e-6
    return input_tensor+noise

ALPHA = 1e-6
def logit(x):
    return np.log(x / (1.0 - x))

def logit_trafo(x):
    local_x = ALPHA + (1. - 2.*ALPHA) * x
    return logit(local_x)
# with_noise=False will print just [1. 1.] after one epoch (due to the /= operation above)
# with_noise=True will remove this issue. Why?

mydata = get_dataloader(data, torch.device('cpu'), apply_logit=False, with_noise=False, normed=True)
with torch.no_grad():
    for n in range(3):
        print("epoch: ", n)
        for i, elem in enumerate(mydata):
            print('batch: ', i, #elem['data'].numpy(), 
                  elem['data_sum'].numpy())
```

I get the following output:

```
[[0.19151945 0.62210877 0.43772774 0.78535858]
 [0.77997581 0.27259261 0.27646426 0.80187218]
 [0.95813935 0.87593263 0.35781727 0.50099513]
 [0.68346294 0.71270203 0.37025075 0.56119619]
 [0.50308317 0.01376845 0.77282662 0.88264119]
 [0.36488598 0.61539618 0.07538124 0.36882401]
 [0.9331401  0.65137814 0.39720258 0.78873014]
 [0.31683612 0.56809865 0.86912739 0.43617342]
 [0.80214764 0.14376682 0.70426097 0.70458131]
 [0.21879211 0.92486763 0.44214076 0.90931596]
 [0.05980922 0.18428708 0.04735528 0.67488094]
 [0.59462478 0.53331016 0.04332406 0.56143308]
 [0.32966845 0.50296683 0.11189432 0.60719371]
 [0.56594464 0.00676406 0.61744171 0.91212289]
 [0.79052413 0.99208147 0.95880176 0.79196414]
 [0.28525096 0.62491671 0.4780938  0.19567518]
 [0.38231745 0.05387369 0.45164841 0.98200474]
 [0.1239427  0.1193809  0.73852306 0.58730363]
 [0.47163253 0.10712682 0.22921857 0.89996519]
 [0.41675354 0.53585166 0.00620852 0.30064171]]

epoch:  0
batch:  0 [2.03671454 2.13090485]
batch:  1 [2.69288438 2.3276119 ]
batch:  2 [2.17231943 1.42448741]
batch:  3 [2.77045097 2.19023559]
batch:  4 [2.35475675 2.49511645]
batch:  5 [0.96633253 1.73269209]
batch:  6 [1.5517233 2.1022733]
batch:  7 [3.5333715  1.58393664]
batch:  8 [1.86984429 1.56915029]
batch:  9 [1.70794311 1.25945542]
epoch:  1
batch:  0 [1. 1.]
batch:  1 [1. 1.]
batch:  2 [1. 1.]
batch:  3 [1. 1.]
batch:  4 [1. 1.]
batch:  5 [1. 1.]
batch:  6 [1. 1.]
batch:  7 [1. 1.]
batch:  8 [1. 1.]
batch:  9 [1. 1.]
epoch:  2
batch:  0 [1. 1.]
batch:  1 [1. 1.]
batch:  2 [1. 1.]
batch:  3 [1. 1.]
batch:  4 [1. 1.]
batch:  5 [1. 1.]
batch:  6 [1. 1.]
batch:  7 [1. 1.]
batch:  8 [1. 1.]
batch:  9 [1. 1.]
```

After the first epoch, the entries that are supposed to give the sum of each input vector returns 1. The reason, based on my understanding, is that the `/=`  operation inside `__getitem()__` overwrites the original array (since it was a shallow copy only). However, when I create the dataloader with `with_noise=True` the output becomes

```
epoch:  0
batch:  0 [2.03671714 2.13090728]
batch:  1 [2.69288618 2.32761437]
batch:  2 [2.17232151 1.42449024]
batch:  3 [2.7704527  2.19023717]
batch:  4 [2.35475926 2.49511859]
batch:  5 [0.96633553 1.73269352]
batch:  6 [1.55172434 2.10227475]
batch:  7 [3.53337356 1.58393908]
batch:  8 [1.86984558 1.56915276]
batch:  9 [1.70794503 1.25945833]
epoch:  1
batch:  0 [2.03671729 2.13090765]
batch:  1 [2.69288721 2.32761405]
batch:  2 [2.17232208 1.42449008]
batch:  3 [2.77045253 2.19023718]
batch:  4 [2.35475815 2.4951189 ]
batch:  5 [0.96633595 1.73269401]
batch:  6 [1.55172476 2.10227547]
batch:  7 [3.53337382 1.58393882]
batch:  8 [1.86984584 1.56915165]
batch:  9 [1.70794547 1.25945795]
epoch:  2
batch:  0 [2.03671533 2.13090593]
batch:  1 [2.69288633 2.32761373]
batch:  2 [2.17232158 1.42448975]
batch:  3 [2.77045371 2.19023796]
batch:  4 [2.3547586  2.49511857]
batch:  5 [0.96633348 1.73269476]
batch:  6 [1.55172544 2.10227616]
batch:  7 [3.53337367 1.58393892]
batch:  8 [1.86984568 1.56915256]
batch:  9 [1.70794379 1.25945825]
```

The same is also true if the noise I add is multiplied by `0.`.

Why is that? Why does it suddenly become a deep copy?

Comment: Can you please trace the problem down and make an actual [mcve]?

Comment: `x /= y` is an *in-place* operator: it modifies the object `x` on which it operates rather than making a new one, unless the object is immutable. `x = x / y` is not *in place*: it creates a new object and binds it to the name `x`. Does that help?

Comment: The code snipped above is complete, it reproduces the issue. I know that the initial bug comes from the in-place operation x /= y (as I have also written). My question is why that suddenly changes when I call the add_noise() function (even when I add 0 there).

Comment: The code snippet is excessive and something much shorter would reproduce the issue if you took the time to prune it down.

Comment: `input_tensor+noise` creates a new array. `input_tensor+=noise` would not. You would have to return `input_tensor` on a separate line then. I used `/` in my example, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Mad Physicist! I had to read it and the code a few times to see the issue:

Without the call to `add_noise()`, the line `data /= (data_sum + 1e-16)`, being in-place, changes the original input array. Hence, every subsequent call to it returns the already normalized data. The call to `add_noise()` creates a new array the way it is coded. The in-place operation then only changes the new array and does not touch the original array (that was the step I missed). Hence subsequent calls return the original, not normalized array.